# Clone react component and its child components

Tags: reactjs

I have three components, App, Row and Column. Clicking the column component changes it's text state. Now I want to duplicate the Row component which contains the Column component as well. But when I duplicate, I get the default text value for Column component and not the changed text state.

Basically when I duplicate Row Component, I want the Column component with the changed text state and not its default state. I just can't get my head around it so please help me out. Thanks!

Below is my code:

**App.js**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.addRow = this.addRow.bind(this)
        this.removeRow = this.removeRow.bind(this)
        this.duplicateRow = this.duplicateRow.bind(this)

        this.state = {
           rows: []
        }
    }

    addRow(){
       this.setState({
           rows: this.state.rows.concat(<Row />)
       });
    }

    removeRow(index){
        this.setState({
            rows: this.state.rows.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
        });
    }

    duplicateRow(index){
        const rows = this.state.rows;
        const dupli = this.state.rows[index];
        const insert = (rows, idx, newItem) => [
            ...rows.slice(0, idx),
            newItem,
            ...rows.slice(idx)
        ]
        const updatedRows = insert(rows, index, dupli);
        this.setState({
            rows: updatedRows
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref="htmlBuilder" className="html-builder container">
                <div ref="content">
                    {
                        this.state.rows.map( (obj, key) => <Row key={key} index={key} removeRow={this.removeRow} duplicateRow={this.duplicateRow} />)
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="pt-non-ideal-state" style={{border:"2px dashed #eee",width:"100%",maxWidth:"100%",paddingTop:30,paddingBottom:30}}>
                    <div className="pt-non-ideal-state-visual pt-non-ideal-state-icon" style={{margin:0}}>
                        <a href="javascrip:void(0)" onClick={this.addRow}><span className="pt-icon pt-icon-add"></span></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Row.js**

```
class Row extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // bindingd
        this.showActions = this.showActions.bind(this);
        this.hideActions = this.hideActions.bind(this);
        this.removeRow = this.removeRow.bind(this);
        this.duplicateRow = this.duplicateRow.bind(this);
        // initial state
        this.state = {
            class: "row",
            actions: false,
            children: [<Column key={0.0} />]
        }
    }

    showActions(){
        this.setState({
            class: "row hb-editor",
            actions: true
        });
    }
    hideActions(){
        this.setState({
            class: "row",
            actions: false
        });
    }
    removeRow(){
        this.props.removeRow(this.props.index);
    }
    duplicateRow(){
        this.props.duplicateRow(this.props.index,this.render());
    }

    render() {
        let actions = "";
        if(this.state.actions){
            actions = <div style={{position:"absolute",top:0,right:0,backgroundColor:"#8BEEEB"}}>
                        <Duplicate action={this.duplicateRow} />
                        <Delete delete={this.removeRow} />
                    </div>
        }
        return (
            <div ref={this.props.index} className={this.state.class} onMouseOver={this.showActions} onMouseLeave={this.hideActions} style={{position:"relative",paddingTop:30,paddingBottom:30}}>
                {actions}
                {this.state.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Column.js**

```
class Column extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        // bindings
        this.change = this.change.bind(this)
        // initial state
        this.state = {
            class: "col-md-12",
            text: "I am a column with class",
            children: [<Txt key="text" text={this.text} change={this.changeText} />]
        }
    }

    ComponentWillMount(){
        this.setState({
            text: this.props.text || this.state.text
        })
    }

    change(){
        const newText = "You changed me..."
        this.setState({
            text: newText
        })
    }

    text(text){
        text = text || "Click to change me"
        return text
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.change} className={this.state.className}>
                {this.state.text} "{this.state.class}" 
                {
                    this.state.children.map( (obj, key) => obj)
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that when calling `splice` on a property of `this.state` you are actually **mutating** the state because splice acts directly on the array. Try using `slice` and `concat` instead.

Comment: Also be aware that the value stored in your `dupli` variable is the reference to an object so any changes you make on the duplicate will affect the original object that `dupli` reference points at

Comment: But I am not doing it directly on the state. Am I missing something?

Comment: `let rows = this.state.rows;`.  `rows.splice(newIndex, 0, dupli);` is the same as `this.state.rows.splice`... And `splice` mutates the array it is working on

Comment: Thanks! I have updated the code. Between, any pointers on the main issue?

Comment: `this.state.rows.concat(<Row />)` — this code smells. Try to keep the state simple, serializable and representable by components.